# Does the multi-valued function $\sinh^i(z)$ have an analytic branch on the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I've tried algebraically manipulating the function but I'm stuck as to how to continue.
$$\sinh^i(z) = \left(\frac{e^z -e^{-z}}{2} \right)^i = e^{i \log \left(\frac{e^z -e^{-z}}{2} \right)}$$
I then tried assuming I'm looking at the principal branch of log and work backwards to see which parts of the image correspond to those of the source but I only really did it with Mobius transforms and I'm not good at those.

Comment: Note that $\sinh(z)$ is zero for $z =i \pi,2 i  \pi, \ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you may do better by looking at the branch points of $f(w)=w^i$ where $w=\sinh z$.

Since this $f(w)$ has a branch point whenever $w=\sinh z=0$, we conclude that these exist at all points given by $z=i(k\pi)$; $\sinh z = -i\sin(iz)$ is zero at such points. Therefore an analytical branch in the upper half-plane (or the lower one) is not possible.

However, the alignment of all branch points along the imaginary axis does imply that an analytic branch may be defined in the *right or left* half-plane.

Comment: "Since this f(w) has a branch point whenever w=sinhz=0" - why is this the case? I understood from the comment and your explanation that there are points where my function is undefined on the upper plane as a result of $\sinh(z)$'s definition and intuited from there that no matter which branch I pick I'll never get a fully defined function on the upper plane.